# Calling Postgres procedure from Java source code is not working

Tags: java, postgresql, weblogic

I'm using Postgres 12 and trying to call a stored procedure from Java source code. When I'm trying to call the procedure from a simple function in a class, it's working and giving output but the same is not working when I'm trying to call this procedure in an application that runs on WebLogic.

```java
public int test(String i_oid, String i_msisdn,String i_cardtype, String i_content, Double i_clientid, String i_smscid) {
    int o_rc = -1;
        
    try {
        stmt = connection.prepareCall("call pkg_sms$enqueue_sm(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        stmt.registerOutParameter(9,java.sql.Types.DOUBLE);
        stmt.setDouble(1, i_clientid);
        stmt.setString(2, i_oid);
        stmt.setString(3, i_msisdn);
        stmt.setString(4, "");
        stmt.setString(5, i_cardtype);
        stmt.setString(6, "");
        stmt.setString(7, i_content);
        stmt.setString(8, i_smscid);
        stmt.execute();

        o_rc = (int) stmt.getDouble(9);

        if (o_rc == 0) {
            log.log_sys(Level.INFO, "SMS to MSISDN:[" + i_msisdn + "] is tested, cliendId:["+i_clientid.toString()+"]");
        } else {
            log.log_sys(Level.INFO, "Fail to test SMS: RC:[" + o_rc + "] MSISDN:[" + i_msisdn + "], cliendId:["+i_clientid.toString()+"]");
        }
    } catch(SQLRecoverableException sqlre) {    
        log.log_sys(Level.ERROR, "#DB_Execution:Calling test1() SQLRecoverableException" + sqlre);
        log.log_sys(Level.WARN, "#DB_Execution:DB Connection Closed = ["+ disconnectDB()+"]");
    } catch(SQLException e) {   
        log.log_sys(Level.ERROR, "#DB_Execution:Calling test() Exception" + e);
        log.log_sys(Level.WARN, "#DB_Execution:DB Connection Closed = ["+ disconnectDB()+"]");
    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            log.log_sys(Level.ERROR, "#DB_Execution:Statement Close Exception" + e2);
        }
    }
    return o_rc;
}
```

The stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pkg_sms$enqueue_sm(
    i_clientid double precision,
    i_oid text,
    i_ms text,
    i_serv_type text,
    i_card_type text,
    i_sub_type text,
    i_content text,
    i_smsc_id text,
    INOUT o_rc double precision DEFAULT NULL::double precision)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO cnp.tbl_sm_queue (seqnum, clientid, oid, ms, serv_type, card_type, sub_type, content, status, smsc_id, create_on)
    VALUES (nextval('seq'), i_clientid, i_smsc_id, i_ms, i_serv_type, i_card_type, i_sub_type, i_content, 'I', i_smsc_id, current_timestamp);
    o_rc := 0;
   
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN others THEN
        get stacked diagnostics
        o_rc   = returned_sqlstate;
            o_rc := - 1 * ABS(o_rc);
           
END;
$BODY$;
```

The error I'm getting:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This statement does not declare an OUT parameter.  Use { ?= call ... } to declare one.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that you use the following syntax when calling a stored procedure with OUT parameter:

```
stmt = connection.prepareCall("{?= call pkg_sms$enqueue_sm(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
```

Comment: that's also not working.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: pkg_sms$enqueue_sm(double precision, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying) is a procedure
  Hint: To call a procedure, use CALL.
  Position: 15


only native call is working for procedure like:
call proc()

Comment: Can you provide the code of the stored procedure?  This error indicates that the stored procedure has only 8 parameters.

Comment: I have updated the code of the stored procedure above. It's showing 8 parameters because I'm giving default value for out parameter